# Синтаксис SASS вместо SCSS

Tags: sass, scss, compass

При создании проекта и подключении к нему SASS через Compass, система формирует набор папок, в папке с файлами SASS - расширение становится - SCSS, синтаксис написания кода там подобен CSS, т.е. необходимо ставить символы - "`{}`" "`;`".

Как можно сделать так, что бы расширение оставалось SASS, и редактор не выдавал ошибку при не написании этих символов.

Благодарю.

Answer (score 0):

Что бы использовать SASS синтаксис необходимо в корне проекта отредактировать файл `config.rb`. При подключению `Compass` к проекту, в конфигурационный файл записан синтаксис `SCSS` по умолчанию.

Находим эту строчку

```
preferred_syntax = :scss
```

И заменяем на

```
preferred_syntax = :sass
```

Более подробная документация по конфигурационному файлу [тут](http://compass-style.org/help/documentation/configuration-reference/).